# Migrate User Between Tenants

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I want to implement a function to migrate a user from one tenant to another.

I know this could be achieved simply by change user's tenant id.

The problem is, I have an order has this user id and tenant id recorded, if I simply updated this user's tenant id, i won't be able to locate the user using the data recorded in the order.

If I have to update all the orders during migrating process, this could take up a long time for a large database.

Since the default PK type for ABP is long, is it possible to replace it as guid or are there any options I could choose?
Thanks.

Comment: you can use [Table("Test")]
    public class Test: FullAuditedEntity<Guid>

Comment: How would `Guid` help?

Comment: you might be doing something wrong! why do you need to change tenantId? maybe we'll have more accurate idea for the solution